# Cakephp HABTM removing extra fields

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have models named **Place** and **Category** which are connected using an HABTM relationship. Now when i read specific fields from **Place**, i get additional fields in the result like this.

```
array(
'Place' => array(
    'id' => '8'
),
'Category' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'CategoriesPlace' => array(
            'id' => '673',
            'place_id' => '8',
            'category_id' => '2'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'id' => '3',
        'CategoriesPlace' => array(
            'id' => '674',
            'place_id' => '8',
            'category_id' => '3'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'id' => '5',
        'CategoriesPlace' => array(
            'id' => '675',
            'place_id' => '8',
            'category_id' => '5'
        )
    )
)
```

)

I dont want this **CategoriesPlace** array to be displayed. Any idea how?

Answer (score 1):

Two cakephp solutions:

```
$this->Place->recursive=-1;
```

before the find.

Or:

```
$this->Place->contain();
```

[contain docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containable)

Edit:
For greater control of the output:

[containable docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)

Put:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

in the model.

Then:

```
$this->Place->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Place',
        'Category' => array(
            'fields'=>array('id')
        )
    )
  )
);
```

It may not work as cakephp adds all the foreign keys it needs to execute a query.

Comment: `array(
 (int) 0 => array(
  'Place' => array(
   'id' => '1'
  )
 )
)`
Now this is the result i'm getting. But i need the **Category** array to be there, just dont need the **CategoriesPlace** array

Comment: Still it doesnt filter the HABTM relationship fields i think.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300262/containable-wont-filter-2nd-level-model-with-habtm-hasmany